# Ruby array delete if and get deleted object

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-2.3

So I have this situation where I need to delete something from an array conditionally, meaning that I want to go through the items in the array and do a test and delete the one that passes the test, and then I want to get that deleted item back. If I exclude the conditional aspect of this then `Array#delete` does what I want basically--returns the deleted item, but can't delete conditionally. On the other hand delete_if removes the item conditionally, but returns the remaining items back in an array.

For the purposes of this question assume the following class:

```
class Foo
  def test?
    #returns true or false
  end
end
```

I can easily reproduce this behavior by doing:

```
index = my_array.index {|a| a.test?}
item_to_delete = my_array[index]
my_array.delete item_to_delete
```

But I was hoping to find something like:

```
deleted_item = my_array.delete_if_and_return_deleted {|a| a.test?}
```

I'm not thrilled about having to go through the array multiple times to get this done :/ first to find the target's index, second to get the target and third to remove the target. Ick.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify it. I wanted to know if there was a method on Array or elsewhere in ruby 2.3 that will remove an object from an array conditionally and return the removed object. As delete_if works, it returns the array of remaining (not deleted) objects and the deleted one disappears into the aether.

Comment: Though inferior to `partition`, `[3,1,4].group_by { |n| n>2 }.values #=> [[3, 4], [1]] ` also works, provided ordering is not an issue.

Comment: thanks for adding another way to do this. I always appreciate seeing multiple solutions--I learn more that way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the [partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method:

```
deleted_items, kept_items = my_array.partition {|a| a.test?}
```

Comment: perfect! thanks. I totally missed that one when going through the Array methods one at a time :/